# On Turan's theorem

Tags: extremal-graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Turan's theorem provides minimum number of edges of a graph on $n$ vertices to surely contain a clique of a prescribed size. This has been generalized to regular graphs.

What additional specializations have been made in the literature if the graph is regular and contains additional algebraic structure?

Answer (score 6):

There are versions of Turan's theorem that add spectral assumptions to regularity.
This one is due to Sudakov, Szabó, & Vu ([CiteSeer link](http://citeseer.uark.edu:8380/citeseerx/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=F77B415BD5C2D89759A8FD28281795DF?doi=10.1.1.57.6852)):

A graph is called an $(n, d, \lambda)$-graph if it has $n$ vertices, is $d$-regular,
and $\max_{i \ge 2} |\lambda_i| \le \lambda$, where $\lambda_i$ are the 
adjaceny-matrix eigenvalues,
largest to smallest.

If for some $r \ge 2$, $d^r \gg \lambda n^{r-1}$,
then every $(n, d, \lambda)$-graph contains a clique of size $r+1$.
They establish bounds on the size of the largest $K_{r+1}$-free subgraph.

In some sense this requires that the 2nd-largest eigenvalue is sufficiently small.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. When I meant structure, I meant something algebraic. I am familiar with Vu's work. It is a good reference.